# Can the zero set of irreducible polynomial, with complex coefficients, in more than one variable, ever be compact in Euclidean topology?

Tags: analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, algebraic-topology

Let $f \in \mathbb C[x_1,...,x_n]$ be an irreducible polynomial, where $n>1$.

Let $Z(f):=\{(a_1,...,a_n)\in \mathbb C^n: f(a_1,...,a_n)=0\}$.

Is it possible that $Z(f)$ is compact in the Euclidean topology of $\mathbb C^n$ ?

Comment: No, for example letting $a_2, ...,a_n\to\infty$ then solve $a_1$ from $f=0$.

Comment: I assume you want to exclude constant nonzero polynomials? Otherwise the zero locus might be empty and thus compact.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven This is excluded by the assumption that $f$ be irreducible.

Comment: @YuDing: could you please elaborate on your comment ?

Comment: @uno. Let $a_2,\ldots,a_n$ be very large and temporarily fixed numbers. The polynomial $f(x,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ on the variable $x$ has a root $a_1$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. Then $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is a zero of $f$, with very large norm in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro If $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=1+x_2-x_3$ then $f(x,a_2,a_2)$ has no root

Comment: In fact, something more is true; so long as it is nonempty, the zero set of any holomorphic function on $n>1$ variables is unbounded. If it is only holomorphic on some bounded region $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}^n$, then the closure of the zero set will intersect the boundary.

Comment: @k.stm Of course that was stupid of me. I did not realize that we are over a field.

Comment: @N.S. Sure but assuming $f$ is non-constant in $x_1$ then for some $a_3,\ldots, a_n$, $f(x_1,x_2,a_3,\ldots, a_n)= \sum_{j=0}^d p_j(x_2) x_1^j$ with $d > 1,p_d \ne 0$  and for every $a_2$ not a root of $p_d$ we have a zero $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots, a_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you already know some basic algebraic geometry, here’s one way to see this:

Let $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $A = ℂ[X_1, …, X_n]/(f)$.  By Noether normalization, going-up and Krull’s principal ideal theorem, there is a surjective and closed map of varieties $X → \mathbb A^{n-1}_ℂ$. As $ℂ$ is algebraically closed, this induces a *surjective* map of classically algebraic sets $Z(f) → \mathbb A^{n-1} (ℂ)$. Being polynomial in nature, this map is continuous both with the Zariski and the Euclidean topology.

Thus, if $Z(f)$ was compact in the Euclidean topology, so was $ℂ^{n-1}$, which is not for $n > 1$.

Comment: ah ugh ... dim $A=n-1$ and $A$ is integral domain ... thank you very much ...

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to assume irreducibility (although the general case follows from this one by decomposing $f$ in irreducible parts). Of course the result hold for the zero polynomial, but not for any other constant polynomial, so we assume $f$ is not constant.

Up to permuting variables, $x_1$ has at least one non-zero exponent in standard form. Then $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_1^ip_i(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ for certain polynomials $p_i$.

Let us show that for all $k$, there exist $|a_2|,\ldots,|a_n|>k$ such that $f(x,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ is not constant. Suppose otherwise, i.e. for all $|a_2|,\ldots,|a_n|>k$, the polynomial
$$f(x,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=\sum_i x^ip_i(a_2,\ldots,a_n)$$
is constant, which means that $p_i(a_2,\ldots,a_n)=0$ for $i\geq 1$.

It follows that for $i\geq 1$, the polynomial $p_i$ is zero outside of a large ball of $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, which implies $p_i=0$ for $i\geq 1$ (as is probably known beforehand; otherwise you can prove it by induction with a similar argument).

Therefore $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=p_0(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, contradicting the fact that $f$ has a nonzero power of $x_1$ in standard form.

Then for $k>0$, choose $a_2,\ldots,a_n>k$ such that $f(x,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ is not constant. Let $a_1$ be any root of this polynomial. The tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is a root of $f$ of euclidean norm $>k$. Therefore $f^{-1}(0)$ is unbounded and in particular non-compact.